# Do I have to install Docker on the remote host, in order to access my application online?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I have bought a space from a host service already and published my files into it and it is currently running successfully.

Now, I have started to learn Docker and use it's advantages like Containerize. I would like to have several instances of my application running on the remote host, in order to achieve this I need several Containers that are using the same image(my application). In order to achieve this I have created an Image and Containers and pushed them to DockerHub, no I want to pull and download them on the remote host, in order to see the Containers via their online address. Now my question is, do I need the Docker to be installed on the remote host? If the remote host is not a dedicated server but the shared one, do I need to install the Docker on it still? Or there is any other way that I am not aware about?

The project is SPA (ANGULAR + ASP.NET WEB API + SQL SERVER)

Comment: you need a [dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) 
(see **d** at the end) to run docker containers

Comment: @vasily.sib But what if, the remote hosting company doesn't support the Docker?

Comment: You may ask support service or find another one

Comment: @vasily.sib So you mean the remote hosting company, need to install the Docker Desktop? Same as mine that I have already installed? Or they need to install a different instance of it, I am afraid I've been confused about the dockerd(d) that you mentioned.

Comment: It depends on what their host OS. Also, if they are on windows, you may find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40320748/2716623) interesting.

Comment: also, [here](http://alexander.holbreich.org/docker-components-explained/) you can find a well described structure of docker components

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to install Docker on your remote host in order to run your image.

If the remote host is a shared one, though, chances are that you are not allowed to install Docker there for security reasons. If you're allowed to run Docker containers on a host, you have effectively root access.

**EDIT**

Since the question about "effectively root access" came up:

Supposed you're on a shared hoster where each user has its environment under /home/user. Now imagine your user can run Docker commands, i.e. is in the `docker` group.
You could simply run `docker run -v /home/anotheruser:/iamaspy alpine` and you could access another user's content in the container on the path `/iamaspy`. Have a look at the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) for further information. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42006123/6482759) you can also find a more elaborate SO answer than mine.

Comment: What's your mean by "you have effectively root access"?

Comment: Also please verify, to install Docker on my remote host, do I need to install the Docker Desktop? Same as mine that I have already installed on my local windows machine? Or they need to install a different instance of it?

Comment: I have a big doubts about _"you have effectively root access"_ too. Can you please share a link to docker docs or maybe some blog posts where this is proved?

Comment: @J.P. Your remote host is pretty likely a Linux server, so there is no Docker desktop. On Linux environments, you can directly install Docker, c.f. [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/). Otherwise, please update your question with more info about your remote host.

Comment: @bellackn The remote host is Windows server, so, it means, the docker desktop needs to be installed. OK?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows Server, but one way or another, you have to run a Docker daemon on this machine. I fear that, especially for a beginner, Windows Server isn't the best environment to get started :) I don't know if regular Docker Desktop works there as there seems to be a special Enterprise solution, cf. [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/).